# When I use filterBy my Vue.js application stops working

Tags: vue.js

When I am using filterBy my application stop working, and nothing shows up in the page the VM instance div is missing form the DOM. What might be the reason?

```
<div  v-else v-for="events in profDetails.events | filterBy events.type">
```

Below is the JSON Format :

```
{
    "usrId": "1",
    "events": [{
        "sdate": "02/13/2017",
        "author": "suthota1@email.com",
        "imgsmall": "images/backgroundhead.svg",
        "usrId": 1,
        "title": "BigFix Detect (Endpoint Detection & Response) Marketing Announce",
        "type": "announcements",
        "edate": "02/13/2017",
        "tags": "",
        "bu": ["Security"],
        "scope": "CISOs, SOC Analysts",
        "contact": "",
        "createTS": "June 01, 2017 @ 04:53 PM",
        "id": 1,
        "region": "North America",
        "imglarge": "images/backgroundhead.svg",
        "kma": "New landing page, demo video, webinar, comprehensive digital campaign, try/buy offer, immersive demos at RSA, analyst quick take report",
        "status": "Published",
        "desc": "IBM launches new rapid threat detection and remediation platform. The top tactic employed by attackers is to avoid being detected in the first place. This has spawned a flood of endpoint detection and response (EDR) tools that have primarily focused on detection of endpoint threats. Unlike other vendors, BigFix sees, understands and acts on all threats on the endpoint through a single platform, detecting malicious behavior and delivering targeted remediation on impacted endpoints enterprise wide in minutes."
    }, {
        "sdate": "07/26/2017",
        "author": "suthota1@email.com",
        "imgsmall": "images/backgroundhead.svg",
        "usrId": 1,
        "title": "IBM X-Force Red Portal 2.0",
        "type": "announcements",
        "edate": "07/26/2017",
        "tags": "",
        "bu": ["Security"],
        "scope": "Technical security testing",
        "contact": "",
        "createTS": "June 01, 2017 @ 04:53 PM",
        "id": 2,
        "region": "North America",
        "imglarge": "images/backgroundhead.svg",
        "kma": "Announce as Tier 1 story at Blackhat for Security",
        "status": "Published",
        "desc": "TECHIBM X-Force Red, is a new global force of the industry's."
    }],
    "status": "SUCCESS"
 }
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-filterBy-Filter

Comment: Which version of Vue are you using?  filterBy was removed in v2 (filter the data in a `computed` function instead.)

Comment: vuejs version 1

Comment: OK -- in that case I think you'll need to show some sample data (what's in `profDetails`, and which elements are you trying to filter out?)  Right now it looks like you're trying to filter each `events` by a field contained inside the same `events`, which doesn't seem likely to be what you actually intend...

Comment: Added the JSON, Hope thats helpfull :)